# Limit comparisons on series with difficult comparisons?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, suppose I have the following series: $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty sin\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Since the inside doesn't converge, does $sin(1/x)$ diverge? I have to use the limit test somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you have
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sin\frac1k}{\frac1k}=1,
$$
which tells you that the behaviour of your series is the same as that of the harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k$.

Note that for big $k$, $\sin1/k>0$, so the limit comparison test applies.